# How to get the image from the fingerprint scanner?

Tags: fingerprint

I'm using C++ and I have to capture image from fingerprint scanner. Is there some libraries for this case? I need free solutions. And better cross-platform solutions, but the aim-OS is Vista. May be there are some methods in Qt4? It would be best solution for me.

Comment: Do you mean THAT fingerprint scanner? Maybe you should give some more information on the model and connection type (USB?).

Comment: I mean fp-scanner in my laptop =) Asus M51Sn

Comment: @KyberProtagonistes: please do not comment on your own question.  Please update your question with additional facts.  Please state the hardware, operating system and which API library you've already read about for reading various devices on whatever computer you're talking about.  Please do not comment.  Please update the question with facts.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to figure out exactly what manufacturer makes the scanner (it's not ASUS -- there are only two or three manufacturers of the sort of capacitive sensors used in laptops.  My bet is that it's a UPEK scanner) and what model it is, then go to the manufacturer's web site and see what tools they provide.  If there aren't any on the web site, contact the manufacturer.

Note that it's very likely that the SDK for the scanner (a) is available only if you sign a non-disclosure agreement and (b) costs money.  If you're lucky, the manufacturer's SDK complies with the BioAPI standard, which will make it easier (note: not "easy") to use your code with scanners from other vendors.

Comment: Thanks, but... I hoped there are some versatile methods for all types of scanners. Like accessing the web-cam.

Comment: My point is that those versatile methods you hoped for don't exist.  The BioAPI consortium is working towards the standards needed, but it's a long way off.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options that abstracts you from the scanner vendor, but they are all paid.
In effect they have a single API that covers most model types/versions.
I recommend you to design your solution applying a design pattern that abstracts your application from the scanner vendor.